# Converting plain password in database to Laravel encrypted password

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called "users" where I have username and password from my users.

The passwords are in plain text. Now I've created a new site with Laravel 6.0 and Auth.

So if a user wants to loggin into my site I need to convert my password plain text to the new password encrypted.

How can I get the "salt" from my Auth and also a tools to get the encrypted password from my plain password and "salt". The reason is because I created a new column in my users table so I want to put there the password encrypted using a query.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I know, I just have plain text because I need to encrypt them to laravel format

Comment: Don't even worry about conversion... Just de-authenticate all users and force them to create a new password. Use Laravel's built in Auth logic to handle hashing them. Also, encryption is not the same as hashing... If you encrypt something, you can decrypt it.

Comment: Never save passwords plain..

Comment: Laravel hashes the password self if you use the laravel auth. If you do not use this and want to (which I highly suggest) run this command:  `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: I did run make:auth and I want to use it, I just don't know how I can login to my site using plain text and laravel to read it as the type of encryption laravel works

Comment: Any specific reason to use Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel `Hash` facade provides secure Bcrypt and Argon2 hashing for storing user passwords.

```php
$password = Hash::make('plain-text-password');
```

The `bcrypt` function hashes the given value using Bcrypt. You may use it as an alternative to the `Hash` facade:

```php
$password = bcrypt('plain-text-password');
```

---

> How can I get the "salt" from my Auth and also a tools to get the encrypted password from my plain password and "salt".

#### Verifying A Password Against A Hash

The `check` method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash.

```php
if (Hash::check('plain-text-password', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

---

#### Update

You can use Command or make a route to change "plain-text" password for existing customers.

Create command **app/Console/Commands/ChangePassword.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ChangePassword extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'change-password';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Plain-text password changer';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users = User::get();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if (Hash::needsRehash($user->password)) {
                $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
                $user->save();
            }
        }

        $this->info('Done..');
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
php artisan change-password
```

After run command, you can try login via `Auth::routes()` routes.

---

#### Or Manually Authenticating Users

```php
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // Authentication passed...
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to put $password = bcrypt('plain-text-password'); I'm sorry I'm newbie at laravel and I want to learn more.

Comment: @Pedronaldo1916 Do you have 2 column for password? Something like old-password (plain) and password

Comment: Nice. I think you need to create command or route to change all users password. Do you experience with command?

Comment: It shows me an error in console Exception trace:  App\Console\Commands\ChangePassword::handle() C:\workindirectory\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illiminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:32        and another error in console is call_user_func_array([])

Comment: Ah.. Got it.. I change my answer.. Just update the model

Comment: @Pedronaldo1916 please check my updated answer. Change `App/Models/User` into `App/User`

Comment: @Pedronaldo1916 glad to hear that.. You can accept answer now

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a function to update your database passwords to encrypted passwords first.

Something like this on web.php, and visit /password-updator on browser

```
Route::get('/password_updator', function() {
 $allusers = \DB::table('users')->get();
 foreach($users as $user) {
  $user->password = bcrypt($user->password);
  $user->save();
}
});
```

Make sure yo backup your database before you proceed!

Or you create a new column called password_hashed first onn users table and update it to experiment.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-bcrypt